# Remove Android webview margin right and left

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, sdk

I am working on a webview app , my problem is that there is a margin on the right and left and i am a beginner i dont know how to remove them please help.
note:please be specific in your answers for eg:add this code in the full screen content in the java box called layout.

Thanks a lot in advance, here is the codes:
**1- layout- full screen activity folder**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
        WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        view.loadUrl("http://google.com");

        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mVisible = true;
        mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mContentView = findViewById(R.id.webView);


        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        mContentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                toggle();
            }
        });

        // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
        // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
        // while interacting with the UI.

    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

// Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);


    }

    private void toggle() {
        if (mVisible) {
            hide();
        } else {
            show();
        }
    }

    private void hide() {
        // Hide UI first
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }
        mControlsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mVisible = false;
```

**2-android manifest in the manifest folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="eizeasta.resale">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

**3-activity full screen in the java folder**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context="eizeasta.resale.FullscreenActivity">

    <!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc. -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:text="@string/dummy_content"
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows. -->

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
            style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/black_overlay"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Trying changing the width and height of webview from matchparent to wrap_content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, just added this code and the webview fitted the fullscreen.

```
mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

Comment: If after applying the code from this answer, your html content becomes too small for comfort, you can use `mWebView.getSettings().setTextZoom(percent)`, to zoom the content to your desired size

Answer (score 0):

Are there any other xml files other than the one you have mentioned? You might have another layout which is the parent. The parent layout having a margin could explain whats going on.

Comment: No other xml files but there is something weird happening,the website in the code opens with margins, but if I open another website like an ad for example it opens with no margins