# webView android right margin is greater than left

Tags: android

I am a complete beginner in android and I am creating a WebView based app.
I Have successfully created my app but in my WebView app, there is much white space on the right side as compared to the left.

I want my viewport to be at the center with as minimal whitespace as possible.

I also took reference from the following question asked on StackOverflow
[Remove Android webview margin right and left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40310175/remove-android-webview-margin-right-and-left)

I tried adding following settings:-

```
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

But this did not remove the whitespace from the right.

**Below are my WebSettings**

```
final WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setCacheMode(webSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

**Below is my Activity_main.xml file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/offline_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="gone">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/image_offline"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="@dimen/offline_message_1_text_size"
            android:text="@string/offline_message_1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/offline_message_2_text_size"
            android:text="@string/offline_message_2"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/try_again_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/try_again"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_footer">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: why are you using multiple cache modes? maybe you are adding a margin or padding on the webview programmatically.

Comment: so, in which file should I go through?

Comment: if you are not using a custom webview, you can look at the file where you initialize your webview.